# Изменить стиль линии графика в полярных координатах

Tags: python, matplotlib

Пытаюсь соединить точки на круговом графике:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.axes(projection = 'polar')
  
# creating an array
rads = np.linspace(0, 23, 24)*15
  
# plotting the ellipse
dots=[]
for _ in range(len(rads)):
    s = np.random.randint(10,50)
    dots.append(s)
plt.polar(rads, dots, 'g.', linestyle='--')
    
plt.show()
```

Смущают какие-то концентрические звезды, которые получаются при этом((
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я-то ожидаю что-то типа такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно просто правильно подобрать значения. Окружность - это `2 Pi`, а с вашими значениями вы делаете по нескольку оборотов круга за один шаг, ну и радиус у вас слишком сильно скачет.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import math


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.axes(projection = 'polar')
  
# creating an array
rads = np.linspace(0, 1, 24) * 2 * math.pi # теперь только один оборот круга
  
# plotting the ellipse
dots=[]
for _ in range(len(rads)):
    s = np.random.randint(45,55) # и радиус не такой скачущий тоже
    dots.append(s)
plt.polar(rads, dots, 'r-', linestyle='--')
    
plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: т.е. в итоге в таких случаях нужно указывать угловую коорднату в радианах, не в градусах?

Comment: @catauggie Абажжите, а почему тогда у вас переменная `rads` называется, откуда это название взялось, это же явно сокращение от `radians`, почему вы там не радианы тогда делали? ))  Но вообще да - и судя по результату, и судя по примеру в документации https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html там должны быть радианы.

Comment: это я пытался сначала добавлоять по точке в цикле с присобачиванием к кажой из них значений из одного датафейма. строилась как раз жуткая звезда... пересмотрев подход, я понял, что я был не прав, и исправил код

Comment: получилось в итоге как-то так https://github.com/catauggie/first-expirience/blob/master/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.ipynb

Comment: Красивое ) Ну хорошо, что разобрались в итоге